# mv with rsync functionality

Tags: find, rsync, mv

I'm trying to merge two directory trees that have many common elements but also each have elements that are only present in one of the two trees. The main issue I am having is that when `mv` encounters two sub-directories with the same relative paths it either keeps the source (with `-f`) or the destination (with `-n`) but I can't make it take the union of both sub-directories. I could of course use `rsync` with `--remove-source-files` but this will actually copy the data and then delete the old files as opposed to a true move. The two directory trees contain several hundred GB of data and are both on same partition so I would love to do a true move if possible for the sake of time.

Right now I have `find * -type file -exec mv -n {} /destination/{}` but this only moves  files from the source to the destination when the target directory already exists. I can preface this command with something like `mv -n * /destination/` but this only brings over the top level directories. Is there any way to do this in a single line? I could  always write a script to check if the directory exists before copying the file but this seems like such a basic task, it seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: Could you give an example of the the before and after directory structures that you have/want?

Comment: What do you want to happen for files that exist on both sides? Always move and overwrite? Delete the source file? Move or delete depending on which one is newest?

Comment: @Graeme The structure you showed below in your example is exactly what I had in mind. Unfortunately, I couldn't find `prename` anywhere so I went with G-Man solution. The files should be the same on both sides so it doesn't matter if it overwrites or now.

Comment: @vaaal, updated with a source for `prename`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Warning: This answer will not work on file systems that do not support hard links (e.g., FAT).

Another option (which may be more portable) is

```
cd source_directory
find . -type f -print0 | cpio --pass-through --null --link --make-directories dest_dir
```

`cpio` (copy in&out) is a dinosaur that predates `tar`. 
Like `tar`, it can create or extract from archives. 
Unlike `tar` (correct me if I’m wrong),
it can copy directory trees with a single command. 
(I guess you could do this with `tar -cf - source option(s) and arguments(s) | tar -xf - destination option(s) and arguments(s)`.) 
That’s what `--pass-through` means. 
`--null` means “expect filenames to be delimited by nulls”;
i.e., read output from `find … -print0`. 
`--link` means “link files from the source directory into the destination directory,
if possible”. 
`--make-directories` needs no explanation.

This can be abbreviated `cpio –p0ld dest_dir`. 
Add `--verbose` or `-v` if you want.

Then, after this finishes,

- Check for collisions and handle appropriately.
- **Verify that your destination directory is populated with hard links.**
- Remove the source directory.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it won't be much different from `rsync` with `--remove-source-files`. Note also that `cpio` is no longer POSIX, it has been replaced by a similar utility called `pax`. `pax` is also in the Linux Standard Base, so should be the most portable, although the reality is that many distros ignore this and have `cpio` installed as default.

Comment: What do you mean, "it won't be much different from `rsync` with `--remove-source-files`? Doesn't that copy the data and then delete the old files? I'm proposing a link followed by a delete; i.e., a "true move", which the OP asked for.

Comment: Sorry missed that, my bad.

Comment: Okay, so this worked well except on FAT file systems... I forgot that hard links are not supported there. I ran it on a good chunk of data and it was removed from the source but not linked at the destination. I'm pretty sure the answer is no but is there anyway to get this data back, short of using some file recovery tool?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `prename` to get what you want. On some distributions (eg Debian/Ubuntu) this should be installed as default and aliased to `rename`. Other distros may use a different `rename`. You could change to the directory above the source directory and do:

```
find source -exec prename 's:^source:/path/to/dest:' {} +
```

This will refuse to move files that already exist in the destination tree and leave empty directories in the case where the directories names overlap, so you will have the remove them after. You can add the `-f` option to `prename` to make it overwrite existing files.

Example:

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/{common,sub1} dir2/{common,sub2}

$ touch dir1/sub1/file dir2/sub2/file dir1/common/common dir2/common/common dir1/common/diff1 dir2/common/diff2

$ tree dir*
dir1
├── common
│   ├── common
│   └── diff1
└── sub1
    └── file
dir2
├── common
│   ├── common
│   └── diff2
└── sub2
    └── file

4 directories, 6 files

$ find dir2 -depth -exec rename 's/^dir2/dir1/' {} +
Can't rename dir2/sub2/file dir1/sub2/file: No such file or directory
dir2/common/common not renamed: dir1/common/common already exists
dir2/common not renamed: dir1/common already exists
dir2 not renamed: dir1 already exists

$ tree dir*
dir1
├── common
│   ├── common
│   ├── diff1
│   └── diff2
├── sub1
│   └── file
└── sub2
    └── file
dir2
└── common
    └── common

4 directories, 6 files
```

Update:

To give a source for `prename`, it is usually comes bundled with `perl` (hence the 'p'). On Debian/Ubuntu it is part of the `perl` package. If you want to get it separately, one of the answerers to this question - [Get the Perl rename utility instead of the built-in rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename) has made a separate repository for it - https://github.com/subogero/rename

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `rsync` to move files rather than copy them:

```
rsync -av --link-dest "$PWD"/src/ --remove-source-files src/ dst
```

In the normal way of things, `rsync -av --remove-source-files src/ dst` will copy files from `src/` to `dst` and then remove the source. By adding the `--link-dest` option and pointing it to the `src/` directory, the target files will be linked rather than copied.

The only caveats that I can see are:

- `--link-dest` is relative to the destination directory so we need to specify the full path to `src/`
- `rsync` won't report files as being copied if they are linked, so the output from `rsync -av --progress` will report no files copied

NB. Tested using a file that consumed 90% of my available disk space. Copying would have failed (90% + 90% » 100%) but linking/moving worked correctly.