# How do I merge (without copying) two directories?

Tags: command-line, merge, move, vfs

I have:

```
$ find 1 2 -printf '%i %p\n'
40011805 1
40011450 1/t
40011923 1/a
40014006 1/a/e
40011217 1/a/q
40011806 2
40011458 2/y
40011924 2/a
40013989 2/a/e
40013945 2/a/w
```

I want:

```
<inode>  <path>
any      2
40011450 2/t
40011458 2/y
any      2/a
40014006 2/a/e
40011217 2/a/q
40013945 2/a/w
```

How do do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Already answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152666/17594).

Here is version adapted to this task:

```
D=$(readlink -f "2"); (cd "1" && find . -type f -print0 | cpio --pass-through --null --link --make-directories "$D") && rm -Rf 1
```

After this command I have exactly what I wanted:

```
$ find 1 2 -printf '%i %p\n'
find: `1': No such file or directory
40011806 2
40011450 2/t
40011458 2/y
40011924 2/a
40011217 2/a/q
40014006 2/a/e
40013945 2/a/w
```

Read notes about usage in the original answer (linked above).