# How do I --move-- the contents of 1 folder (with subfolders) to another folder (with the same subfolder names as the source)?

Tags: files, move

I think this is best explained with an example.

Example:

```
/mnt/mystorage/source
    => folder1
        => file11.txt
    => folder2
        => file21.txt

/mnt/mystorage/destination
    => folder1
        => file12.txt
    => folder2
        => file22.txt
```

The resulting file structure in the destination should be:

```
destination
    => folder1
        => file11.txt
        => file12.txt
    => folder2
        => file21.txt
        => file22.txt
```

I know I can use rsync with the "--remove-source-files" flag but that would mean it's copying the files/folders first. In my real world example, the source folder is several TBs in size and copying this much will take awhile. From my experience, moving a file/folder to another location in the same partition often means Linux (maybe any OS in general) just changes the file/folder references/pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mv with rsync functionality](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152651/mv-with-rsync-functionality)

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127712/merging-folders-with-mv/

Comment: And also look at [how-to-integrate-mv-command-after-find-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154818/how-to-integrate-mv-command-after-find-command)

Comment: Just move the source folder?! It's almost like a rename. It won't touch any of the content.